# social count wordpress plugin

Tags: wordpress, plugins, social-networking

Hello Im using a social share plugin. It works correctly but the share counts are not showing. can somebody help me find the problem of this plugin? you can download the plugin documents at https://wordpress.org/plugins/responsive-social-share/

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

This plugin can not support counting so for counting you can follow below steps.

Please save and add this js file into your theme folder and call it into header or footer.
http://w.sharethis.com/button/buttons.js

After that add you social icon like this.

```
<span class='st_sharethis_hcount' displayText='ShareThis'></span>
<span class='st_fblike_hcount' displayText='Facebook Like'></span>
<span class='st_googleplus_hcount' displayText='Google +'></span>
<span class='st_twitter_hcount' displayText='Tweet'></span>
```

also you can change button style as par your requirement. for more please visit below link.

http://support.sharethis.com/customer/portal/articles/475260-examples#sthash.PE66l82M.dpbs